Cannot access Filament admin panel pages except dashboard in the production website

    "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
    "filament/filament": "3.2",
      "php": "^8.1",


I am facing one error in this laravel jetstream filament project in production, I cannot access my blogposts and users pages except "the dashboard" in the filament admin panel, everytime It says 500 server error GET https://ilmbeacon.com/admin/posts 500 (Internal Server Error), But when I change "app_debug" to "true" this error appears,
Error in filament admin panel:
"Error
PHP 8.2.21
10.48.16
Class "NumberFormatter" not found"
Even I enabled the "ini extension" in the c-panel  and also added it manually in the c-panel PHP INI EDITOR file like this here see it below
extension=php_intl.dll
I solved this error when I deployed this project at the very first time, at that time only I enabled the ini extension in c-panel, but after some days when I wanted to post some blog posts, I could not access the pages!
I do not know how to solve it!
I do search it here and there some answers suggest that do add ini extension in the server by contacting the administrator or hosting provider is it the solution to this?
Please guide me as I am new to development!
I try enabling ini extension in the c-panel and also manually add these lines one by one checking them in PHP INI EDITOR extension=php_intl.dll, extension=php_intl, extension=ext/php_intl.dll
But "the Class formatter nor found" doesnot disappear I donot know what the exact solution to this!
